# Definition of quasiprojective variety by Shafarevich

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In "Basic algebraic geometry" Shafarevich defines a quasiprojective variety as "an open subset of a closed projective set". Then he goes on to say "Obviously a closed projective set is quasiprojective". What does he mean by this? It reads to me like "X is a closed projective set => X is an open projective set". Why?

And how does his definition compare to the definition of quasiprojective as "locally closed"?

Many thanks.

Comment: He means that a closed set is an open subset of itself with respect to [induced topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology). I think.

Answer (score 1):

He means "open" relative to the "closed projective set"; the latter gains a subspace topology as a subset of $\mathbb P^n$. It would be good to review the [subspace topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology). This is just a topological condition and has any number of equivalent guises: it's the intersection of a closed subset of $\mathbb P^n$ and an open subset of $\mathbb P^n$; it's a (relatively) open subset of its closure in $\mathbb P^n$; it's a relatively closed subset of some open subset of $\mathbb P^n$. In particular, it's the same as being locally closed.

He probably uses the given definition because it's the most natural one in the classical language: the central objects are the closed subsets of projective space and everything should descend from those. In the language of schemes that he introduces in Volume II this becomes more subtle.